# Scroll position of page changes after I select option from Dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

Recently I have downloaded select2.min.js Version: 3.5.1 and applied to my  asp page. Things are working fine but I am facing one issue that when ever I select any options from drop down list, scroll position of the page is getting reset to centre of the screen. 
my asp code is..

```
<asp:DropDownList CssClass="SelectClass" ID="drpTypeofRooms3" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

an Script for the same is as follow

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $(".SelectClass").select2({
            placeholder: "--Select--"
        });
        $(".SelectClass").each(function (x) {
            $("#s2id_" + this.id).attr("tooltip", $("#" + this.id + " option:selected").text());
            $("#s2id_" + this.id).attr("title", $("#" + this.id + " option:selected").text());
        });
        $(".SelectClass").change(function () {
            $("#s2id_" + this.id).attr("tooltip", $("#" + this.id + " option:selected").text());
            $("#s2id_" + this.id).attr("title", $("#" + this.id + " option:selected").text());
        });
    });
```

I know this issue is little strange but I have wasted almost 2-3 days on it.
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

I used latest version i.e. select2-4.0.0-beta.3 which solved my problem.